# moving data between google sheets automatically

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

im new to google sheets and need a bit of help completing some script. I want to set up a timesheet that will allow me to transfer total working hours of an individual entered into an employee google timesheet. This data needs to be transferred to a "manager authorisation" sheet and cleared ready for the following week. I want to then build an authorisation button for the manager that will copy the data and into a summary sheet and copy the data into a master payroll sheet for all employees based on employee number.

I have worked out how to transfer data from one sheet to  a fixed position then clear it. But having difficulty when trying to move to a different location as the date for the data has changed e.g. Ted works 10 hrs w/c 10/1 I can move from his sheet to another set destination. The following week he works 20hrs not sure how to change the desitination to based on a date.

help please

Comment: The last part of your question is a little confusing becasue we can't see your data structure.  Are you moving the data to a sheet that already has W/C dates and if so what is the structure.  If you're moving to a sheet with a list then I think you can use *append* to add your data to the bottom of the list.  I would always recommend storeing your data in a list and then you can display it in a more friendly way on another sheet as required.

Comment: Thanks for your response Gordon.

Comment: Thanks for your response Gordon. I have laid out the data as it would look in the google sheets. Employee A has worked 17 hrs at rate 1 for w/c 20th Feb 2017. This would be copied into the summary weekly sheets for the 20th. Future weeks would populate under the relevant w/c date    
w/c 20th Feb 2017  Mon Tues Weds Thurs Fri
      
Working Hours  rate 1 6    6           5            0           0
Working Hours  rate  2
Manager Summary  20-Feb-17 27-Feb-17 06-Mar-17 
Employee A      
Work rate 1

Comment: Apologies , I believed it would appear as a table.

Comment: It may be easier if you edit your question and add a screenshot.  When you say into the "Summary Weekly sheets for the 20th" does that mean that there will be a seperate sheet for each week?

Comment: Hi Gordon. I am really struggling to format the tables and get a screen shot to load so you can see the layout. The summary weekly is a single sheet with column headings for weeks running across the top. Employee weekly data will feed into the relevant weekly column.

Comment: Like I said in a previous comment I wouldn't recommend storing the data in the way you want to display it.  It's better to store it as a list and then you can generate lots of different views as required.  Have a look at this demo I've put together https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZN789fVtDY8gU8iWKY_z-JGgEUKNFlen7_VlCDem41E/copy?usp=sharing there is not script in it to copy data yet but it gives you an idea of what you can do if you store the data as a list.